# ValueError: Cannot assign value: must be an instance

Tags: django, ajax, m2m

I have four fields in a model, one of which is a foreign key field and the other three are m2m fields. The form is opened in the modal, but the data is not being saved, Error given below. I don't understand what I did wrong. I would be very grateful for a little help.

Model:

```
class ProductAttributes(models.Model):
    product     = models.ForeignKey('Product', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    size        = models.ManyToManyField('ProductSize', blank=True)
    colour      = models.ManyToManyField('ProductColour', blank=True)
    cupsize     = models.ManyToManyField('ProductCupSize', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

Form:

```
class ProductAttributesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product     = forms.IntegerField(label=('ID'),required=True, disabled=True)
    size        = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ProductSize.objects.all(),widget=Select2MultipleWidget, required=False)
    colour      = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ProductColour.objects.all(),widget=Select2MultipleWidget, required=False)
    cupsize     = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=ProductCupSize.objects.all(),widget=Select2MultipleWidget, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = ProductAttributes
        fields = ['product','size','colour','cupsize']
```

Template:

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<form id="Form" method="post" action="{% url 'accpack:products_attributes_create' product %}" class="js-product-create-form col s12" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% crispy form form.helper %}
</form>
```

View:

```
def save_attribute_form(request, form, template_name, pk):
    data = dict()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            data['form_is_valid'] = True
        else:
            data['form_is_valid'] = False
    context = {'form': form, 'product':pk}
    data['html_form'] = render_to_string(template_name, context, request=request)
    return JsonResponse(data)

def attribute_create(request, pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProductAttributesForm(request.POST, initial={'product': pk})
    else:
        form = ProductAttributesForm(initial={'product': pk})
    return save_attribute_form(request, form, 'main/products/partial_product_attribute_form.html', pk)
```

ajax:

```
 var saveForm = function () {
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
      url: form.attr("action"),
      data: form.serialize(),
      type: form.attr("method"),
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
        if (data.form_is_valid) {
          $("#modal-product_attribute").modal("hide");
          console.log(data.form_data);
        }
        else {
          $("#modal-product_attribute .modal-content").html(data.html_form);
        }
      }
    });
    return false;
  $("#modal-product_attribute").on("submit", ".js-product-create-form", saveForm);
```

error:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djangoproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 220, in __set__
    self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "111": "ProductAttributes.product" must be a "Product" instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have an error in your forms.py.

```
    class Meta:
        model = ProductSize
        fields = ['product','size','colour','cupsize']
```

Here, the model should be

```
      model = ProductAttributes
```

Since the model you specified here `ProductSize` does exist, submitting form will just create another instance to `ProductSize` model without those specific fields and error messages. You can check your admin page.

EDIT ******
2. Based on what you added in the question and the error message, it looks like in `attribute_create` you are passing product's pk. Now in the `attribute_create`, you are passing initial dict `{'product': pk}`. This is wrong, because, in your `ProductAttributesForm`, the `product` field should be an instance rather than a `pk`.

You need to refer product as

```
product = Product.objects.filter(pk=pk)
initial = {'product':product}
```

The current error message will be gone, but you will have other errors.

Comment: It's a serious thing that I missed, thanks. The form is not submitting now. Getting an error `the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. I wish django can give a warning message about this kind of situation, something like, fields were not found.. When there is no error message, it is hard to find solution.

Comment: I just edited my comment, plz take a look.

Comment: are you trying to submit form via ajax? 500 error often related to ajax. do you have ajax code?

Comment: `self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
ValueError: Cannot assign "111": "ProductAttributes.product" must be a "Product" instance`.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying with ajax

Comment: ```Cannot assign "111": "ProductAttributes.product" must be a "Product" instance``` this looks like you are passing pk=111 from ```ProductAttributes```, not the pk of the ```product```. it is possible that 111th productattributes object has product.pk = 10. I think it is most likely that in your template, you are passing wrong pk. most likely you are just passing productattributes.pk rather than productattributes.product.pk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225277/discussion-between-abzal-ali-and-ha-neul).

Comment: Looks like you added your template in the question, could you also add your Ajax(JavaScript) part?

Comment: I updated my answer, also left message in the chat.